# What "time precise" garbage collection algorithms do exist?

Tags: language-agnostic, garbage-collection

Which garbage collection algorithms can recognize garbage objects **as soon as they become garbage**?

The only thing which comes to my mind is reference counting with an added cycle-search every time a reference count is decremented to a non-zero value.

Are there any other interesting collection algorithms which can achieve that? (Note that I'm asking out of curiosity only; I'm aware that all such collectors would probably be incredibly inefficient)

Comment: There was a posting today on Hacker News about realtime GC. (I did not read it)

Comment: You could run the mark-and-sweep GC after each reference change. Though that would be extremely inefficient.

Comment: @svick: You're right. Now i feel stupid :)

Comment: @leppie Real-time GC means that the code whose memory allocation is governed by the GC can be real-time, for example by guaranteeing a certain percentage of CPU utilization over a sliding time window. It has nothing to do with promptness of deallocation. In fact, this goal (like many other goals) is in conflict with it..

Comment: @delnan: Ahh OK, like I said, I did not read it :)

Comment: There is none, efficiently determining if an object is garbage is like np-hard. Detecting garbage cycles sounds easy but is in reality incredibly hard to do. In the worst case, the work is equivalent to doing a full mark phase in a mark&sweep collector.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist: I already suspected so... do you have any references which explain/evaluate/prove this? If so I would accept that as the correct answer to this question.

Comment: I don't have a proof, but The Garbage Collection Handbook p.66-75 describes it well. There is no way (that I know of) around the fact that ref counting is local but cycle detection requires a global analysis of the object graph.

Answer (score 0):

Though not being a garbage collection algorithm, **escape analysis** allows reasoning about life-time of objects. So, if efficiency is a concern and objects should be collected not in all but in "obvious" cases, it can be handy. The basic idea is to perform static analysis of the program (at compile time or at load time if compiled for a VM) and to figure out if a newly created object may escape a routine it is created in (hence the name of the analysis). If the object is not passed anywhere else, not stored in global memory, not returned from the given routine, etc., it can be released before returning from this routine or even earlier, at the place of its last use.

The objects that do not live longer than the associated method call can be allocated on the stack rather than in the heap so they can be removed from the garbage collection cycle at compile time thus lowering pressure on the general GC.

Answer (score -4):

Such a mechanism would be called "heap management", not garbage collection.

By definition, garbage collection is decoupled from heap management.  This is because in some environments/applications it is more efficient to skip doing a "free" operation and keeping track of what is in use.  Instead, every once in a while, just ago around and gather all the unreferenced nodes and put them back on the free list.

== Addendum ==

I am being downvoted for attempting to correct the terminology of heap management with garbage collection.  The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) agrees with my usage, and what I learned at university, even though that was several decades ago.  Languages such as Lisp and Snobol invented the need for garbage collection.  Languages such as C don't provide such a heavy duty runtime environment; instead the rely on the programmer to manage cleanup of unused bits of memory and resources.

Comment: This sounds like a terminological comment to me, not actually an answer to the question.

Comment: Also I don't think you're right. Reference counting *is* a form of garbage collection.

Comment: @wallyk: You mentioned a wikipedia article (why not link it?). I looked "heap management" up on wikipedia which redirects to "memory management" which mostly deals with os-level details and allocator techniques, which is not exactly related to my question. Also, as svick already commented, your post didn't really answer my question. Your answer basically explains why real-life collectors don't work in a matter proposed in my op, a fact I'm already aware of like i made clear in my question. However feel free to edit your answer to actually answer the question and i will upvote it.

Comment: @BillAskaga:  I did link it:  it is where it says "Wikipedia article", but the graying out makes it hard to see.   I'll give some thought to answering the question, but the terminology is tripping me up.

Comment: @wallyk: This graying, really didn't see that, sorry! Well terminology is a tough thing here since garbage collection simply means automatically reclaiming unused space. In practice all algorithms in use overestimate the lifetime of objects in order to be efficient, so i chose the term "time precise" to contrast that, since i didn't know the right terminology.

Comment: @wallyk The article you linked to says reference counting is a form of garbage collection. And it uses the term “heap management” only once, without actually explaining it. Which part of the article do you think says what you're saying? Though maybe I misunderstood what you're trying to say.